# How to pass List of custom objects in spring Rest Template

Tags: spring, rest, templates

I have a method in RestController say:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsersByUserIds(
            @RequestParam List<Integer> userIdList) {
        List<User> users = userService.getAllUsersByUserIds(userIdList);
        if (users.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

How should I call this in my client using Spring Rest Template

`restTemplate.getForObject()` method.

Cheers Vemu!!!

Comment: Another scenario is if I have to call this method with list of user objects;-                                                                       @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
 public ResponseEntity<User> deleteAllUsers(List<User> userList) {
  userService.deleteUserListForTenant(userList);
  return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}

Answer (score 0):

You should call with an array of integers.

```
    var array = [1,2,3];
    $.ajax({
      url: "/users?userIdList="+array
    }).done(function() {
      $( this ).addClass( "done" );
    });
```

And with restTemplate

```
String result = restTemplate.getForObject("yourContext/users?userIdList={ids}", String.class, "1,2,3");
```